# asp.net mvc dao

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm looking for a book or an online tutorial on asp.net using C# that teaches how to setup MVC and DAO.

In Visual Studio, I first create an "ASP.NET Web Application", then I add the Controller, Model and DAO Class Libraries.

I then want to understand the concept of Entity Base Creator Class. How this is used.
Undestand how Generics work, eg `Result<T> and Result<List<T>>`.

I would like to understand what do I put in the Controller.cs, the Model.cs and the Dao.cs and EntityCreator.cs. Do these all relate to the Entity (tables) setup in my Database?

Comment: ADO or DAO? question title and body are not aligned, can you decide? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a pretty good ASP .NET MVC aplication with DB.

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/create-a-movie-database-application-in-15-minutes-with-asp-net-mvc-cs